# Magento Installation Information

Tags: magento, xampp, magento-1.4

I am using Xampp 1.7.0 and the version of Magento I am using is 1.4.2.0

Apart from basic changes in the ini like

```
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_mcrypt.dll
extension=php_mcrypt_filter.dll
extension=php_mhash.dll
```

I made 3 other changes

1. First I replaced a file in apache/bin/
   I replaced libmysql.dll with a newer version of libmysql.dll
2. In the next step of the installation i used 127.0.0.1 in place of localhost
3. After complete installation in order to login to the admin section I had to comment a section of a particular file.

The location of the file was
`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php`
The section I commented was lines 86 to 101

```
/*
if (!$cookieParams[’httponly’]) {
    unset($cookieParams[’httponly’]);
    if (!$cookieParams[’secure’]) {
        unset($cookieParams[’secure’]);
        if (!$cookieParams[’domain’]) {
            unset($cookieParams[’domain’]);
        }
    }
}

if (isset($cookieParams[’domain’])) {
    $cookieParams[’domain’] = $cookie->getDomain();
}
*/
```

After This all of it seems to be working fine. My question is why the 3 changes I have mentioned are necessary in order to make Magento work.

Answer (score 2):

1. magento needs certain extensions
2. you get better results by using domain name
3. fails to create cookies on localhost so you better give your localhost a name like local.host and add it to the host file